# How to represent a bound method and object as a string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, repr

How can i have this:

```
<bound method B.mutate_segment of <foo.B.B object at 0x0000000001269518>>
```

printed like "mutate segment of B"?

Comment: maybe add your class definition first? `foo.B.B` seems odd here.

Comment: foo.B.B here is that i am getting class B from another module called foo.py, so for printing i don't need the name "foo" to appear.

Comment: then why is the method bound on `A`? Post your code, you'll make it easier for everyone to help.

Comment: besides all the previous, why would you want to alter the `repr` of the  `method` type? Apart from doubting if that's even possible, why would you want to do that?

Comment: i made a mistake, the method is bound on B. I corrected the question.
I need this for it for the log file, so that it looks comprehensible.

Comment: Hey, read the question I linked as a duplicate. You can't really do this for the `method` type since you can't redefine `__repr__` for it (and can't create a specialized sub-class for it). I'm still curious though, why do you want to do this?

Comment: ok, thank you, I will look into it. I need this for logging during a very long search process and it would be better if it looks more comprehensible among thousands of logged lines.